# Phone is not booting

Tags: adb, root-access, fastboot, unbricking

I recently bought a new Moto G4 Plus. I tried to root it.

When I installed the `.zip` file it finished successully. I rebooted the phone but it did not boot.

So I went into recovery mode and installed CyanogenMod 13. After that, I tried to reinstall the original (XT1463) firmware. It also finished successfully.

I rebooted the phone and now it is totally dead. What do I do?

Comment: So instead of fixing the initial problem (which would have been simple), you continued to compound the issue by trying more and more stuff? Anyway, what state is the phone is now? What do you mean by "totally dead", can you get to the bootloader, or won't it even turn on?

Comment: @acejavelin is right. We need more details.

Comment: > it did not boot Is it stuck on the boot animation (never ending) or does it stop before loading the boot animation? Also, did you wipe data and cache after flashing the device?

Answer (score 0):

**You should be wiping the data before rooting it.** It might be **bricked** or if you try opening the recovery mode **wipe and clear every data** on the device then reboot. **Wait for it to boot.**

Sometimes it works with this method but you should search the internet for millions of methods for millions of android device models out there.

**Sorry if your device is bricked that's a bad feeling.**